# Installer keeps crashing (squashes error)

Tags: system-installation

I’ve been trying to install elementary OS on my girlfriend's laptop for the better part of the day, but the installer keeps crashing, with errors like this. Any advice?
I can go into elementary without installing and play around for a bit, it’s just whenever I try installing that there are problems.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hay Fred

sounds like this issue may be related to the following problem.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SquashfsErrors

give some of the options a try on the link supplied and let us know how you go.

Is that a MAC your installing on?

""Cheers
G